# How i create an instance of viewmodel on notification when using dagger android

Tags: android, mvvm, notifications, dagger-2, dagger

I am using MVVM with a dagger in my Android app. I have attached my Activity with a ViewModel, where I call API's and it's working great.

I have a scenario if I am in the background and the app receives a notification and I want to call the API from the ViewModel for the reusability but dagger not allowing me to access the same API from ViewModel.

What can I do?
Can I use another class or repository, and call that instance from both notification or ViewModel.

Thanks

My ViewModel code:

```
public class HomeViewModel extends BaseViewModel {

private static final String TAG = "HomeViewModelTimber";

@Inject
MainApi mainApi;

@Inject
RequestManager requestManager;

@Inject
AlertRepository alertRepository;

@Inject
HomeViewModel(MainApi mainApi, SessionManager sessionManager, CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable,
              SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider,
              AlertRepository alertRepository) {
    super(sessionManager,compositeDisposable,schedulerProvider);
    this.mainApi = mainApi;
    this.alertRepository = alertRepository;

}
 void getAlertById(int alertId, IHome iHome){
    mainApi.getAlertById(getSessionManager().getJwtToken(), alertId)
            .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Timber.tag(TAG).i(" getAlertById %s", Constants.SUBSCRIBE))
            .doOnComplete(() -> Timber.tag(TAG).i(" getAlertById %s", Constants.COMPLETE))
            .doOnError(disposable -> Timber.tag(TAG).i(" getAlertById %s", Constants.ERROR))
            .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
            .subscribe(getAlertById -> {
                if (getAlertById != null){
                    if (getAlertById.getPayLoad() == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    PayLoad payLoad = getAlertById.getPayLoad();

                    if (payLoad.getFolder() == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                   }});
```

I want to access "getAlertById" from notification

Comment: Share your viewmodel code

Comment: I have added my ViewModel code in the questions

Comment: Can you please share that how you are injecting the ViewModel in your Activity?

Comment: ViewModelProviders.of(this, providerFactory).get(HomeViewModel.class);

Comment: What you can do create a Service and all your service manager and api call will go into another repository, So it will get abstracted from ViewModel instead of reusing ViewModel.

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala Firstly, Thanks for the response. Secondly, I have used this approach yesterday and it's working great. 
But what MVVM says, that you call server API in ViewModel and call local database API in a repository. So, this approach is against this flow. That's why I was thinking to reuse my ViewModel. If there is any kind of approach/way.